# dropdown align dropdown-toggle right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can i right align the dropdown-toggle in the bootstrap dropdown? here's my code and a jsfiddle, you can see the arrow pointing down is besides the text, i want it on the right.

https://jsfiddle.net/9a83n353/

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-block text-left" style="background-color: white; border-color:#dee4ed" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Active</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item">Active</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Inactive</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CSS to rotate the arrow:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Add CSS float to right align:

```
float:right;
```

Comment: Thanks, it also seems adding the `float:right` adjusted the position of the arrow, thanks to Dev Bunker's response I also added a `margin-top`

Answer (score 9):

**To right align the menu toggle**

You can use `flexbox` properties on the button:

```
.is-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsufr8kf/2/)

**To right align the menu**

Add the class `dropdown-menu-right` to your menu as described in the docs:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74hx3zwo/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a float right to the .dropdown-toggle::after. It looks something like this:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: .3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    border-top: .3em solid;
    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
    border-left: .3em solid transparent;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `absolute` position then align the dropdown icon to left or right by giving `right: 0%` or `left: 0%`. Add margin if you like so the dropdown icon does not stick with the border.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: That's only working. Thanks!